# Why can't i give these lat and long values to google map?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am using google maps but i can't get map marker for these kind of lat and long values.

Tirunelveli     Latitude:`8.44 N`   Longitude:`77.44 E`. How to convert these to values which can be used by google maps?

I used this but there is no place in the map view area,

```
function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(8.44, 77.44), 13);
        var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(8.44, 77.44));
         map.addOverlay(marker);

        map.setUIToDefault();
      }
    }


<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just remove `N` and `E`.
Valid values are just floats with dot (NOT with coma!).

latitude: `8.44`

longitude: `77.44`

Comment: Is it centering your map properly ? Just marker is not visible ?

Comment: Have you called `initialize()` ?

Comment: I used your code and it works fine. I prepended before your JS `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>` and in body I wrote: `<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>` and it works fine - I see map and marker too.